# PasswordSignInAsync not working in some cases

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, passwords

This code works

```
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        var crt_user= await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);
        string password = user.PasswordHash;
        var userResult = _userManager.CreateAsync(crt_user, password).Result;

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(crt_user, password, false, false);


        return Json(result.Succeeded);
```

But when I get rid of the line with CreatSync it does not anymore whereas it does not create any user (same user).

PLease help

My Program.cs file (Identity Options ?)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.



builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, RoleStore>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();

//...
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Are you indicating that if you remove a "create user" operation then the code no longer performs a "create user" operation?  And this is unexpected?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: As an aside... Calling `.Result` directly on your `Task` is almost always the wrong approach.  You should *probably* be making use of the `await` keyword instead.

Comment: @David.

I don't want to create a user and if you look at the line you see that it would create the same user so I get a non blocking error ("cannot recreate same user") but the PasswordSignInAsync return "Succeedeed"

When i delete the _userManager.CreateAsync line (which is useless) it does not succeed anymore !!!!

Comment: @David I don't understand your second point

Comment: So `PasswordSignInAsync` only works for newly created users? Can you share your `IdentityOptions` configuration please?

Comment: @Pieterjan...that is not what I am saying...My PasswodSignInAsync always returned false so I had the "funny idea" to create the user first (because I could not find a way among all the passwords and the CBase64 errors I had)...my idea was that the password format would be ok if i create the user through a refrence code first (because I had no idea what Hashing was).

I thought 'if it creates it it will use it according to what c# wants".

Comment: The _userManager.CreateAsync never worked because it was trying to create the same user (and I did not know at first that it was impossible)

Amazingly adding that line made my PasswordAsync call successful even if does not create any user !!!

My PasswordAsync is no more succesful if i delete the _userManager.CreateAsync call !!!

Something to do with instantiation ? I am not experienced enough in C# to easily understand ;)

Comment: @Pieterjan...thanks...added my program cs in the main post

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why you are not getting this kind of errors when adding UserStore and RoleStore. But you can try below code.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, string>>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, RoleStore<ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, string>>();
```

You just have to pass parameters in UserStore and RoleStore.